# If $f(0)$ is undefined, can we infer that $f(0)=f(0)$?

Tags: logic

Suppose we have $\{0, 1\} \subset X$ and partial function $f$ on $X$ such that

> $\forall a:[a\in X \land a\neq 0 \implies f(a)=1]$

We say that $f(0)$ is *undefined* here. Can we nevertheless infer that $f(0)=f(0)$?

The way I see it, since both $f$ and $0$ were previously introduced, we should be able to do so. I don't see how $f(0)=f(0)$ could lead to any inconsistencies

Comment: What does $f(0)$ mean?

Comment: Just because something isn't inconsistent doesn't mean that it can be inferred. If I say $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, it wouldn't be inconsistent to say $\lambda=1$ but it's not a theorem either.

Comment: Compare the statements 1) “$f$ has no value at zero” and 2) “The value of $f$ at zero is the value of $f$ at zero” to the statements a) “Elon has no flux capacitor” and b) “The flux capacitor of Elon is the flux capacitor of Elon”. (I’d personally say that 2) and b) are vacuously true, yet meaningless. Some argue that the use of the definite article *the* in “the flux capacitor of Elon” implicitly states the flux capacitor’s existence, rendering the statements false. By analogy, 2) would be false, too.)

Comment: @copper.hat Since $f(0)$ is undefined, it is probably meaningless. $f(0)\in X$ can neither be proven nor disproven.

Comment: Uh..no.  If something doesn't exist it doesn't equal anything.  Not even its (non-existent) self.  @k.stm  Consider these two statements. "Elon's flux capacitor runs on gasoline" is vacuously true but the apparently equivalent statement "Gasoline fuels Elon's flux capacitor" is clearly false because gasoline which is exitent does no such thing.  The statements probably are not equivalent but... okay, either $f(0)$ is meaningless and $f(0)=f(0)$ is maningless.Or $f(0)$ exist as a concept. As a concept $f(0)$ is a non-existant things. I'll say non-existant things cant equal... but it's all moot.

Comment: @Jam What is wrong with having a theorem: $\forall f,X, 0, 1:[\{ 0, 1\}\subset X \land \forall a:[a\in X \land a\neq 0 \implies f(0)=1]\implies f(0)=f(0)]$?

Comment: @fleablood Yeah, it’s all moot. : )

Comment: If think if $f(0) = f(0)$ is vacuously true (which I'm okay with) then-- The green fifty pound thought Alexander the Great had about Bill Gate's kitten =  the square circles used by Sam Oxnard who was the second president of the United states-- is also vacuously true (which I'm also okay with).

Comment: @fleablood Vacuously true suggests that $\{0,1\} \subset X \land \forall a:[a\in X \land a\neq 0\implies f(0)=1]$ is always false. It isn't.

Comment: Your symbolic logic seems to be saying that $\{0,1\}$ is a subset of of some undefined $X$ and that for all $a$ if $a\in X$ and $a\ne 0$ then it will follow that $f(0)=1$ for an unspecified $f$.  Well, this could be either true or false depending on whether $0,1$ are in $X$ or whether $f(0) = 1$ or not, but what this has to do with anything is utterly beyond me.

Comment: @fleablood Correction: that should be $\{0, 1\} \subset X \land \forall a:[a\in X \land a\neq 0 \implies f(a)=1]$

Comment: So you are saying if that if $a \ne 0$ then $f(a) = 1$?  Um, *why* are you saying this and why do you think it is true (or false)?  I honestly have no idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: "f(0)∈X can neither be proven nor disproven."  I disagree.  I'd say that Peter, the tap dancing penguin of Mars $\in \mathbb N$ is very easy to disprove.

Comment: But can we say Peter the tap dancing penguin of mars $=$ Peter the tap dancing penguin of mars?  I think that depends on the meaning and interpretation of $=$.  Whether it makes sense to talk about $f(0) = f(0)$ or $\sqrt{\text{babar, the elephant}} = \sqrt{\text{babar, the elephant}}$ or $\frac 10 = \frac 10$ or not, I think there is definitely no *point* in talking about $f(0)$, $\frac 10$ or $\sqrt{\text{babar, the elephant}}$ doing *anything* because none of those things exist.

Comment: @fleablood I want to know if being allowed to infer $f(0)=f(0)$ in this case (where $f(0)$ is undefined) would cause any problems, i.e. inconsistencies. I don't see how, but I might have overlooked something.

Comment: I would say that "infering" $f(0)=f(0)$ *implies* $f(0)$ exists (WHICH IT ABSOLUTELY DOES NOT) and whether you can or can not do it you shouldn't.  Can you infer that $\sqrt{\text{babar, the elephant}}=\sqrt{\text{babar, the elephant}}$? Whether vacuously true or not, it *is* a meaningless statement.  And $f(0)$ is *EVERY BIT* as meaningless as $\sqrt{\text{babar, the elephant}}$.

Comment: Also it doesn't matter if infering it is consistent or not.  It doesn't make it true or meaningful.  Assuming even numbers are pink and odd numbers are blue doesn't cause any inconsistencies but it's an utterly meaningless thing to say.  Numbers don't have colors and $f(0)$ doesn't have value.

Comment: @fleablood $f(0)=f(0)$ would imply that $\exists a: a=f(0)$, namely $f(0)$ itself.  It's weird, but if it doesn't lead to an inconsistency, I think I could live with it.

Comment: Yes it does lead to an inconsistancy.  To say "there exists an $a$ so that $a = f(n)$" leads to "The $a$ so that $a = f(0)$ exists" which leads to "$f(0)$ exists".  Which is false.  So that's a rather *immediate* and very major inconsistency.

Comment: This leads to the "A living unicorn exists" fallacy.  If something is living then it exists.  So a living unicorn exists.  So ... unicorns are real.

Comment: @fleablood We know the value of $f(a)$ only for non-zero values of $a$ in $X$. In this case, that value is $1$. Knowing only that $f(a)$ exists without knowing its value or even whether or not $f(a) \in X$ is really something of  dead end. Needless to say, no inconsistency can be demonstrated in this case.

Comment: But you might as well ask what $f(\text{babar,the elephant})$ is equal to.  $0$ is *not* in the domain of $f$ and that's all there is to it.  Speculating about the output of something not in the domain of a function is useless and its no more useless to speculate if it's a number, a polynomial, or an elephant.  If it isn't in the domain, it isn't in the domain.

Comment: @fleablood  On further consideration, I think I will have to be more careful about the expressions to which I apply reflexivity among other things. If f(0) is undefined, I shouldn't be using it to infer f(0)=f(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,  After *long* and pointless debate I finally see the problem:

We have $f:X \to X$ and we have $\{0,1\}\subset X$ and we know that $f(a)=1$ if $a\ne 0$ and that is all we know.

Now you said quote unquote:

> We say that f(0) is undefined here

NO!!!! we must absolutely do !!!not!!!! say that.  We say that we do not *know* whether $f(0)$ is defined or not.

As it's  *partial* and not a total function we do not know whether $0$ is actually in the domain or not.  If $0$ is *not* in the domain then $f(0)$ is undefined and there is no point in talking about it at all.  $f(0)$ does !NOT! exist.

If on the other hand $0$ is in the domain then $f(0)$ exists and $f(0)$ *IS* defined.  We just have no freaking clue what it is.  In which case, *of course*, $f(0) = f(0)$.

But we can't infer that $f(0)$ exists at all.  If it doesn't exist then .... it doesn't exist.  And we can't talk about it as though it does.

So ... to answer your question:  If $f(0)$ exists then $f(0) = f(0)$.  If $f(0)$ does not exist then $f(0) = f(0)$ is utterly meaningless.

Comment: I have come to agree with you and have updated my program to reflect this. It avoids a lot of weirdness if not outright contradictions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In a typed system, the question doesn't make sense because we know beforehand what the domain of $f$ is : whether it's $\{0,1\}$ or $\{1\}$; in the first case the answer is trivial and in the second case the answer is that the expression "$f(0)$" is not well-typed so $f(0)=f(0)$ "can't be pronounced" in a sense.

In a non-typed system such as ZF(C), the question is different. I assume by "partial function" you then mean " a relation $R\subset X\times Y$ such that for all $x\in X$ there is at most one $y\in Y$ with $(x,y)\in R$".

In that case, the expression $P(f(x_1),...,f(x_n))$ where $P$ is a sentence with $n$ (or more) free variables is an *abbreviation*, and what it is an abbreviation of will give a different answer to your question. I don't know whether there's an agreed upon consensus of what it is, but I can think of at least two common ways of defining it :

$\forall z_1,...,z_n, (x_1,z_1)\in R\land...\land(x_n,z_n) \in R \implies P(z_1,...,z_n)$

or

$\exists z_1,...,z_n, (x_1,z_1)\in R\land...\land(x_n,z_n) \in R \land P(z_1,...,z_n)$

In practice, both these things work equally well, because we never try to evaluate this sentence for $x_i$ not in the domain of definition of $f $ (those $x$ such that there is $y$ with $(x,y)\in R$); but when you're looking at things "on the edge" such as what you're asking, it's important to see what the claim is an abbreviation of .

Here, $f(0)=f(0)$ could mean "$\forall z_1,z_2, (0,z_1)\in R\land (0,z_2)\in R\implies z_1=z_2$", in which case it would be  *true* (by assumption on $R$); or it could mean "$\exists z_1, z_2, (0,z_1)\in R\land (0,z_2)\in R\land z_1=z_2$", whose truth value would *depend* on whether $0$ is in the domain (it would be true if $0$ were in the domain, false otherwise)

We see that neither of these is fully satisfactory on an intuitive level : we don't want $f(0)=f(0)$ to be true or false if $f$ is not defined on $0$, we want it to be... well not defined ! or ill-posed or whatever synonym of that you prefer.

Another approach would be "$P(f(x_1),...,f(x_n))$ is defined only if $x_1,...,x_n$ are in the domain of $f$, otherwise it can't be used", but that would lead to other problematic situations (for instance, what if we can't prove that $x$ is in the domain of $f$ and we can't prove that it's not in the domain, then are we allowed to use $f(x)$ ?)

In the end, the best way to deal with this (in my opinion) is to remember that in ZF(C), everything that is not written only with $\in$ or logical symbols is an abbreviation, and that those abbreviations behave the way we want them to *when they are used in the context for which they were conceived*, and so to be careful and only use them in that context (in particular some abbreviations are equivalent in the context we use them in but not equivalent in other contexts; this example being a great example of that). In other contexts, try to see what the abbreviation can mean and what is relevant to the situation, and if necessary go back to the actual sentence with $\in$'s and logical symbols (or at least go back as far as is needed to ensure that there is no ambiguity)

Another conclusion one can draw from that is that ZF(C) is ill-adapted to a lot of mathematical purposes - to the way a "working mathematician" actually thinks. That is one of the motivations for other systems such as type theory (specifically homotopy type theory) or category theory that are closer in their implementation to how mathematicians actually work and think.